# VBA + Send Mail from Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

I got below code in my Word Document (office 2007) to send a mail with attachement 
It throws syntax error (file not found) at line

.Attachement.Add "C:\abc.txt"

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim item As Object
Dim subject As String
Dim msg As String

    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")

    msg = "Enter Message here"
    subject = "Enter subject here"
    Set item = outlookapp.createitem(0)

    With item
        .to = "some1@aaaaa.com <mailto:some1@aaaa.com> "
        .subject = subject
        .body = msg
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add "C:\abc.txt"
    End With

    End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I have added a further note to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code above and it worked for me. Can you attach a file located somewhere other than the root of C, for example, c:\docs\ ?

EDIT Re Comment

If the path has spaces, you will need extra quotes:

```
strfile="""c:\abc def.txt"""
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for adding an attachment to an item should have the file name enclosed in brackets.

Try using

```
.Attachments.Add ("C:\abc.txt")
```

instead of

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\abc.txt"
```

Comment: Which version are you using? As I said, the code works as it stands.

Comment: Sorry guys it all works, problem was with filepath having spaces.  My filepath is c:\H & I\abc.txt.  How can i get space recognised in VBA.  if was html have using %20 for space.  Any clues ?